# I have a textfile sorted in columns. How can I search a single column for a matching string and then print the entire line

Tags: linux, unix, search

How can I print that line which that value appears. Is it also possible to specify which columns I would like to print instead of printing all columns. This is for linux

Comment: Please, post some sample data with the expected output. Don't post them as comments or images. Thanks.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. What exactly do you mean with "search a single column for a matching string"? A column that is equal to a given string or that contains the string? Add an example to the question as already requested in James Brown's comment.